# Using the min-width in CSS

Tags: html, css

i am having problems with using the min-width; code in CSS,

I have a menu bar that i would like to fix so it doesn't decrease in width as the browser size changes, my problem is that when i try min-width:1000px; this doesn't work,

Please will you take a look at my CSS and see if there are any errors,

CSS:

```
#bar {  
margin-top:55px;
min-width:1000px center;
max-width:1920px;
height: 30px;
background: #2E2E2E;
border: 3.2px groove #FFD700;
min-width:1000px; }
```

Thankyou for your help

Comment: `min-width:1000px center;` is invalid... you may only use length units or percentages (and also only one value). Also subpixel values like `3.2px` makes not much sense either.

Comment: ohh i thought that was a real valid line in CCS, ill change it and see if it makes a difference

Comment: Is your menu bar a table or a div? because if it's a table, you don't need min-width, just width.

Comment: if you're trying to center an element, don't add the keyword `center` to width, but use `margin: 0 auto` instead (the `0` can be any value)

Comment: you are also defining `min-width` twice.

Comment: Please describe your problem better... you are not providing enough information.

Answer (score 2):

remove this `min-width:1000px center;`

and have your css like this for the widths

```
#bar {
    max-width:1920px;
    min-width:1000px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By what i understand.. in CSS     `min-width:1000px center;` will not work properly. So remove the word     `center` from that I have also made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XfY52/) please see it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried out your css, and it stays 1000px wide even in a tiny window.
You could try to remove one of the min-width you have declared, I suggest the first one.

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because your div is using the `max-width` property.

Try to use the `width` based on percentage and you'll understand the power of `min` and `max` width.

[See here.](http://jsfiddle.net/r2V6t/) or:

```
#bar {  
    margin-top:55px;
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: #2E2E2E;
    border: 3.2px groove #FFD700;
    min-width: 300px; 
}
```